# Passing list as a parameter to a function in c

Tags: arrays, c, parameter-passing

I want to pass multiple values as a comma separated list to a function and accepting that list into an array variable. Something like(though it is not compilable):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void passValueAsList (int arr [],int len) {
    int i;
    for (i=0;i <len;i++)
         printf ("%d, ",arr [i]);
 }

 int main () {
       passValueAsList ({1,2,43,5,4,21},6);
       return 0;
  }
```

I don't want to store list into array before passing rather I just want to pass array in place.

Thanks.

Comment: When you get an error from the compiler and you want to ask about that, copy & paste the error from the compiler in your question.

Comment: The compiler is smart enough to avoid storing something in memory when it's not necessary. For example, `{ int j=3; f(j); }` will do the same thing as `f(3);` without first storing a 3 somewhere.

Comment: "As storing may take some space in the memory...." Yes, it will (or registers). Are you working on a target with severely limited resources? If using a few dozen bytes is a major concern, might be time to upgrade your hardware if you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use compound literals. to pass an array like that.

ISO C99 supports compound literals. A compound literal looks like a cast containing an initializer. Its value is an object of the type specified in the cast, containing the elements specified in the initializer; it is an lvalue.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void pass_value_as_list(int arr[], int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
}

int main() {
       pass_value_as_list((int []) {1, 2, 43, 5, 4, 21}, 6);
       return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @NickS. This is what exactly i wanted.

Comment: Is it supported in C11?

Comment: @learner I found description about compound literals in  C11 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) 6.5.2.5 Compound literals. So yes it's supported

Answer (score 1):

```
passValueAsList ({1,2,43,5,4,21},6);
```

This is invalid C syntax, plain and simple.

The correct syntax is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void passValueAsList (int arr [], size_t len) {
    size_t i;
    for (i=0;i <len;i++)
         printf ("%d, ",arr [i]);
}

int main () {
    int arr[] = {1,2,43,5,4,21};
    passValueAsList(arr, sizeof arr / sizeof *arr);
    return 0;
}
```

**edit**

C99 introduces [compound literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html), so this would be also
possible:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void passValueAsList (int arr [], size_t len) {
    size_t i;
    for (i=0;i <len;i++)
         printf ("%d, ",arr [i]);
}

int main () {
    passValueAsList((int[]){1,2,43,5,4,21}, 6);
    return 0;
}
```

> I don't want to store list into array before passing rather i just want to pass it into array. As storing may take some space in the memory and that's why i wanna pass as comma seperated list.

Note that even with the compound literals the array will be still stored
somewhere in memory, `passValueAsList` gets still a pointer to the start of the
location of the array. The only difference with the previous code is that you
don't have a variabe in the `main` function.

The [assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/sASJU5) of both versions is identical.

Comment: I already know this way. But i want something like as i mentioned in the question above.

Answer (score 1):

With C, you can do that with a variable argument list:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_macro_va_arg.htm

But you have to somehow have a marker so that the function you're calling knows when to stop pulling items off of the call stack.

Your example calling code, as written, requires C++.  In C++11, you can have the function take a std::vector as a parameter, and pass the values as in your example calling code.